# RSelenium is not working

Tags: r, selenium

I try to install and run a simple example for R Selenium package using this:

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "Chrome")
remDr$open()
```

In the last code I receive this:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

I tried some workarounds from google but nothing worked. What can I do?

Comment: assume you have chromedriver installed? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: My OS is Windows 7. I tried to give in the path the chromedriver.exe file with this `startServer(args = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Users/Desktop/chromedriver.exe"), log = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)` but it dind't worked

Comment: add the location of you chromedriver.exe. in your system PATH. Restart R session then `require(RSelenium)`, `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")` and `remDr$open()` should work. Just tested on Windows 7 and it works. My chromedriver sits in my Python scripts folder which is in the system path from python install.

Comment: I tried this in windows 7 but again I still face the same problem

Comment: So in Command Prompt if you type `echo %PATH%` you see the directory that chromedriver.exe resides in listed?

Comment: @amwill04 no I can't see the path in this

Comment: Then you havent added the .exe to the list of paths you computer will look for executable files. Basically you pc doesnt know where to look for the chromedriver to launch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments:

Click `start` 
Select `Control Panel` > `System` 
Select `Advance system settings`
Click `Environment Variables...`

Under `System Variables`
Scroll to `Path` and double click
At the end of `Variable value:` add `;C:\path\to\directory` that holds the chromedriver.exe file. Note the `;` that separates the paths

Restart your R session and you should now be able to run:

```
> require(RSelenium)
  RSelenium::startServer()
  remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
  remDr$open()
```

**EDIT**

For RSelenium to operate with chrome you first need to download `chromedriver.exe` you can download this from `https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads`. Once downloaded unzip the folder and place chromedriver.exe where you would like to store it.

The directory that you store `chromedriver.exe` and add to your system PATH can be anywhere you choose. As stated in comments, for example, mine currently resides in `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

Comment: In the path to the directory should I add the exe file i.e. C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application or C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome ?

Comment: The directory you want to add to the path is where chromedriver.exe sits. So for example; my chromedriver.exe file lives in `C:\Python27\Scripts` directory so in my PATH system variable I have added `C:\Python27\Scripts`

Comment: And this path could be different from the initial Chrome installation I made from browser. Because this path is for Chrome as it is for user. I can't see any file name chromedriver.exe

Comment: see edit. You need to download chromedriver.exe. This is what makes it work. For details see `https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium`

Comment: Thank you this worked as well for `phantomjs` drivers