# RSelenium not working with Firefox

Tags: r, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, rselenium

I know my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124857/rselenium-is-not-working), but he's trying to use Chrome while I'm trying to use Firefox (47.0.1).

So basically, I'm trying to use RSelenium. Here is my code :

```
> library(RSelenium)
> checkForServer()

> startServer()
> mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
> mybrowser$open()
```

And with that last line, I get the following error.

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
         Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
         class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

I tried removing-reinstalling the `RSelenium` package. I also tried what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231417/4348534) recommends, with no result.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit 1 :**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSelenium_1.3.5 RJSONIO_1.3-0   RCurl_1.95-4.8  bitops_1.0-6    foreach_1.4.3   httr_1.2.0      XML_3.98-1.4   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.1.2         tools_3.2.3      codetools_0.2-14 iterators_1.0.8  caTools_1.17.1
```

Comment: can you post `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Done, see edited question.

Comment: Possibly a java issue. Have you tested that R is communicating with Java?

Comment: How would I test that ?

Comment: can you load rJava package? I have noticed that although it is not used explicitly by RSelenium it can be a good way to test for the connection between R and Java especially on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Can you try installing from github:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
```

Then run

```
RSelenium::checkForServer(update = TRUE)
```

then retry. Selenium recently put a beta version of Selenium 3.0 on the download tree which was unaccounted for see https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/79. I will look to update a new version to CRAN once some additional fixes have been incorporated.

UPDATE:

There is a new version of `RSelenium` on CRAN now.

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer(update = TRUE)

selServ <- startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("http://www.google.com")
mybrowser$close()
selServ$stop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried both github and CRAN install, I still get the same error though.

Comment: There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812342/latest-version-of-rselenium-and-firefox/38813114?noredirect=1#comment64994382_38813114 . If you continue to have issues consider using Docker. There is a new vignette explaining its operation http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: After the error occurs you can run `mybrowser$value$message` for additonal information on what the issue maybe.