# Latest version of RSelenium and Firefox

Tags: r, selenium, firefox, rselenium

When I try to open the RSelenium I receive this error

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException
```

The version of Firefox I have is

```
Firefox version: 480b10
```

According to [this](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/78) I tried to update the server version

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
unlink(system.file("bin", package = "RSelenium"), recursive = T)
checkForServer(update = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver()
Sys.sleep(5)
remDr$open()
Sys.sleep(5)
```

but the problem still exist. Does anyone face this problem? Any possible solution?

Comment: The problem is solved if we use Firefox 46 version

Comment: If you are using firefox 48 you will need the gecko driver see https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Firefox 48 on-wards the gecko driver/ marionette will be needed to run Firefox with Selenium.

If you have Firefox 48 you can run the gecko driver as follows:

Refer to the guidelines

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver
2. Download the relevant gecko driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
3. Add it to your PATH or refer to the location when starting binary (see below)

```
# get beta selenium standalone

RSelenium::checkForServer(beta = TRUE)
# assume gecko driver is not in our path (assume windows and we downloaded to docs folder)
# if the driver is in your PATH the javaargs call is not needed
selServ <- RSelenium::startServer(javaargs = c("-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=\"C:/Users/john/Documents/geckodriver.exe\""))
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE))
remDr$open()
....
....
remDr$close()
selServ$stop()
```

The above currently requires the dev version of `RSelenium`. Alternatively you can download the Selenium binary from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html . Pick the 3.0 beta 2 binary to currently run with Firefox 48. Run the binary

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:/Users/john/Documents/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems logical but when I go to test your answer I receive this error Error in `RSelenium::checkForServer(beta = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (beta = TRUE)`

Comment: @Jake you will need to install the dev version of `RSelenium`. `devtools::install_github("ropensci/Rselenium")` . Alternatively you can start the server manually I have added a note on this.